# How to change maximum no of file descriptors open in linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, file-descriptor, epoll

When i try to open max number of simultaneous socket connection using epoll , it stucks on 1024 .After this it give "Too many files open" error . I know that this is not the limit .I tried to change nofile parameter value in  /etc/security/limits.conf but i only have read-only permissions there.Is there any method to increase the number of file descriptors opened simultaneously?

Comment: Try `ulimit -n 2048`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the documentation for `ulimit` which governs this an other limits.

- See e.g. [Why is the number of open files limited in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux)

This gives you an answer, you can try setting `ulimit -n`.

Comment: I changed the ulimit -n value but then too i was able to open only 1024 file descriptor.

Comment: @sanyamjain there is a possibility that the parent process had limited fds already. You might need to do the ulimit as root, or somehow make it a direct descendent of `init` (PID 1). I'm not a guru here, but just a thought in case it helps you get started again.

Comment: What *is* in `/etc/security/limits.conf`? Have you tried to run the program from the same shell you did `ulimit -n` in?